# PHP mysqli_fetch_array returning NULL

Tags: php

I have a data base with 3 columns nEspe2,nEspe3 an nEspe4. The query works fine, and $result2 is TRUE(1). When i print $result2, the result i obtain is like this:

> mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 3
>   [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )

The code i use is the next:

```
$queryEspecialidad = "SELECT nEspe2, nEspe3, nEspe4 FROM namesEspe WHERE nEspe1 = '$especialidad'";
if( ($result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$queryEspecialidad))!= FALSE)
{
            print_r($result2);
            echo "QueryEspecialidad realizada correctamente<br>";
            $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
            if($row2 == NULL){echo "Se obtiene NULL de row2XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX<br>";}
...<more code>...
}
```

$row2 always is NULL. I tried with mysqli_fetch_row too with the same problem. Each query returns only 1 row with the 3 colums (some columns could be empty).

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Try using `mysqli_fetch_all()` as a test - does it return the one row or not? Also try using `mysqli_data_seek($result2, 0)` to make sure, you don't skip the first row somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem. It ocurres when the SELECT have '`' or similar accents. NavyCat works well but if the SELECT is made from php, the query fails.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in boolean (and NULL) comparisons, I recommend to use `===` and `!==`. Otherwise e.g. integer 1 would equal `true` as well if you don't.

@Vipul
Second, `mysqli_fetch_array` returns `NULL` if no more rows are left, so OP is right with that statement.

Anyway, I reproduced your setup locally and everything ran as expected, no "Se obtiene NULL de...." appeared. To me, it looks like you somehow skip the first and only row.

Comment: You were right. Thanks for advantages about boolean comparisons too. The problem were the accents. That is why the query did not worked.